# What is the purpose of angular's isLeafNode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular 1.3.0 defines the following function [(here on github)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9e7cb3c37543008e6236bb5a2c4536df2e1e43a9/src/Angular.js#L694):

```
function isLeafNode (node) {
  if (node) {
    switch (nodeName_(node)) {
    case "option":
    case "pre":
    case "title":
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this function isn't used anywhere in the angular codebase (at least not the base module) and isn't documented. What's it's purpose? I can't think of anything that `pre`, `option`, and `title` have in common.

Comment: weird. option and title can't have child elements, but pre can. Very strange. A little googling turned up nothing.

Comment: I've digged into its git history and found that the `isLeafNode` function is there since the beginning of the angularjs repo.

The last code that use the `isLeafNode` was removed by this commit [52ee1ab5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/52ee1ab5eb0f3197453b26c60a70239ac3fffea7#diff-1d54c5f722aebc473dbe96f836ddf974L674).

Comment: @chiliNUT `title` and `option` can both have text nodes as children.  `pre` can have more, but this omits all of the void elements (which legitimately can't have children) entirely.  What's weird about this function is it has seen version history.  It looks different in 1.0 than it did in 1.2 and now in 1.3, but it wasn't actually used in any of them.  Bug?

Comment: text nodes but not element nodes, so I would consider something with only text nodes to be a leaf node

Comment: From what @runTarm mentioned, looks like it was previously used to set html of nodes, where the setting would be deferred to using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` for nodes which angular didn't want to support adding...more than one text node child? Seems like a fix for some edge case that should have been removed a while ago?